# hyperv vm not reachable from another computer in network

Tags: hyper-v

I am trying to setup a cluster. I have 2 laptops in my LAN.

1. Laptop 1 windows VM with hyperv enable
2. Laptop 2 running ubuntu on bare metal.

In laptop 1,  I created a VM (ubuntu) using hyperv with default switch. Now I am trying to connect from laptop2 to vm running in laptop 1, but ping doesn't reach the vm.

On the other hand, hyperv vm is able to connect with laptop 2.

I have disabled firewall in hyperv vm and laptop 2.
Could somebody please help me setup network such that connection in both direction is possible? Below are ip addresses details in cases needed.

**Laptop 1 host IP details**

```
Wireless LAN adapter Wi-Fi:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::d0aa:e43:2164:18c8%21
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.73
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.254
```

**Laptop 1 hyperv switch IP details:**

```
Ethernet adapter vEthernet (Default Switch):

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::718d:fd08:76a:c25a%54
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.35.129
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.240
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :
```

**Laptop 1 Hyper v based  ubuntu VM IP details:**

```
eth0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.35.139  netmask 255.255.255.240  broadcast 192.168.35.143
```

**Laptop 2 IP detail**

```
wlp13s0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.1.83  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.1.255
        inet6 fe80::42eb:609b:b991:7db4  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
```